# Why can't $x$ be negative in $x^{\ln{y}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

According to wolfram alpha, the domain of $x^{\ln{y}}$ is $x>0$ and $y>0$ but putting $(-1,1)$ for $(x,y)$ I get a perfectly fine answer of 1?

$y>0$ makes sense, since $\ln{y}$ is only defined there. But why must $x>0$ as well. The only other problem I see is $x = 0, y = 1$ as then we get a $0^0$ which is not defined.

#### I can't see why $x>0$! (exclamation, not factorial)

Comment: Perhaps a case of Wolfram Alpha playing it safe. What happens when $x=-2$ and $y=e^{1/2}$?

Comment: Aha, but surely this isn't the <b> domain </b> of the function then. I thought the domain was the values for which the function is defined?

Answer (score 1):

When $x < 0$, the result of $x^{\ln y}$ is only real at some cherry-picked points. I suppose WA wants to make it a real function.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$x^{ln(y)}=(e^{ln(x)})^{ln(y)}=e^{ln(x)ln(y)}=(e^{ln(y)})^{ln(x)}=y^{ln(x)}$

Therefore, if you accept that $y > 0$ you should also accept that $x > 0$ as well

Comment: Note that $x=e^{\ln(x)}$ only if $x>0$, which we a priori don't know.

Comment: That's not true, $ln(x)$ and $e^x$ are defined by their Taylor series for negative (and complex) numbers, and the equality $x=e^{ln(x)}$ holds also for $x<0$

Comment: If we want to play with complex numbers, then $\ln y$ is not even uniquely defined, and neither is exponentiation $a^b$ in general.

Comment: True, I guess this is a good place to mention Branch-cuts in the disclaimer :-)